# Pre-computation of jacobian multiplication $J^\intercal_\eta \, J_\eta$ in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus

Is there some computation beforehand of the Jacobian of spherical coordinates map $J^\intercal_\eta \, J_\eta$? Spherical coordinates is the $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ map from $[0, 2\pi] \times [-\pi, \, \pi]$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$given below:

\begin{equation}
\eta(u) = \rho \begin{pmatrix}
\sin(u_1) \, \cos(u_0) \\
\sin(u_1) \, \sin(u_0)\\
\cos(u_1)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

The jacobian matrix is, therefore, equal to $\frac{\partial}{\partial(u_0, \, u_1)} \, \eta(u)$.

Comment: What is $J_\eta^T J_\eta$ ?

Comment: Fixed. I have no computational tool to operate on this multiplication.